# Query_string not returning anything in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello All i am having a problem that when i was using query_string with mappings given below everything was working fine i am just using default analyzers with no filters.

```
mappings : {
    places_area1: {
      properties:{
        area1         : {"type" : "string", "index": "analyzed"},
        city         : {"type" : "string", "index": "analyzed"}
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but now when i am trying to use query_string with this mapping it is not working can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong, i guess its because of whitespace tokenizer but why.

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_wildcard": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": ["filter_wildcard"]
          },
          "synonym_term": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["filter_term"]
          },
          "simple_wildcard": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "filter_term": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword", // here you have to write this only for tokenizer keyword but not for whitespace
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
          },
          "filter_wildcard": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mappings : {
    places_area1: {
      properties:{
        area1         : {"type" : "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "simple_wildcard"},
        city         : {"type" : "string", "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "synonym_term"
          },
          "raw_wildcard": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "synonym_wildcard"
          }
        } },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what word or string you are trying to match with `query_string`?

Comment: i am trying to search starting with Ban so query is Ban*

Comment: hey chintan can i add you on facebook ??

Comment: what document your query should match?

Comment: dont focus on document its already there because when i am using wildcard search query it is returning Bangalore. So i guess problem is somewhere else ??

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be your query is lowercased because by default `"lowercase_expanded_terms"` is true

```
 {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "state",
          "query": "Ban*",
          "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
        }
      }
    }
```

Now this should match Bangalore